# Irreversibility and organisation of trajectories in the phase space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, reversibility

I am currently thinking about the irreversibility paradox. I am not working in this area and my question is certainly not original but I couldn't see it stated in that form yet.

I can't grasp how are the trajectories of an Hamiltonian dynamic are organised in phase space. Consider a system such as an ideal gas. Here are some fact that I believe are correct, but feel contradictory.

1. reversing velocities on the phase space preserves the Liouville measure
2. for each trajectory, reversing velocities leads to another trajectory. On one of them the entropy is increasing while on the other one, the entorpy is decreasing. Hence both categories occupy the same volume of the phase space.
3. the Hamiltonian dynamic preserves the Liouville measure, so when time flows, the trajectories do not get concentrated in a tiny portion of the phase space.
4. if we follow a trajectory that decreases entropy, the tiniest deviation from it will take us back to a trajectory that increases entropy.

How can the 4th point hold if the previous ones are correct? Shouldn't we expect that trajectories that decrease entropy are surrounded by an equal amount of trajectories that increase and decrease entropy?

Comment: There is no paradox. In reality there are no systems with finite phase space. All real physical systems are open. We are simply approximating almost closed systems with Hamiltonians with finite phase space. It's that approximation that causes the trouble and that leads to the well known but practically useless Poincare recurrence theorem.

Comment: @FlatterMann you should write a detailed and full answer elaborating the details, the subject deserves it.

Comment: @hyportnex At most I could point out in more detail that the OP has a number of conceptual problems. Hamiltonian systems don't have an entropy. Entropy change  is defined as reversible heat flow over temperature. This requires that we have contact with a thermal bath, which a Hamiltonian system doesn't have.. and if we make a such a contact, then a Hamiltonian systems stops behaving like a Hamiltonian system completely because we have introduced friction. OK, maybe you are right. Somebody should write an answer explaining the conceptual problem. I am sue somebody already has.

Comment: @FlatterMann don't be so sure; just say yourself ["I am somebody"](https://youtu.be/iTB1h18bHlY) and do it!

Comment: @FlatterMann You can perfectly define an entropy function, by associating to a microstate $\omega$ the value $\log|X_\omega|$, where $X_\omega$ is the set of all microstates corresponding to the same macrostate as $\omega$ (and $|\cdot|$ counts the microstates, say using Liouville measure in the present context). That's what Boltzmann did. I have added a reference to this type of things at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I know we can and how, but we are doing it at the cost of inviting the Poincare recurrence theorem into physics. That's the "paradox" the OP is talking about. It is an entirely unphysical thing to do. I hope that one day this obsession of physics with teaching reversible reversible dynamics as the foundation of descriptions of nature will stop. Nature is irreversible. We know how this happens and why. Irreversibility does complicate the math a little bit, of course, but it removes a lot of rather strained reasoning from physics and it agrees with the observations.

Comment: @hypertonex I simply don't care to kick off a fight by presenting a non-mainstream view today. Maybe another day. You all know the problems with statistical mechanics and the divergence between Hamiltonian mechanics and reality in the t-> infinity limit just as well as I do. I am sure that a really good theorist has even written a really good article or textbook about it, already, that is just not well known.

Comment: There is no paradox. The mechanisms responsible for the emergence of irreversible macroscopic behavior are well understood since Boltzmann's time.

Comment: @FlatterMann I hope that you change your mind about writing this up, I do not even think that you are actually in disagreement with the "orthodox" view. Instead I think your view is giving an actual experimentally testable reason for how the principle of Bernoulli-Cournot manifests itself in statistical mechanics, see Cournot in 
http://www.glennshafer.com/assets/downloads/disappear.pdf; this is the Shafer from the "Dempster-Shafer" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory.

Comment: @hyportnex I'll think about it. I am coming from the very opposite end of the spectrum, though. To me the only certain things are death and taxes. You got to pay the man, especially in physics, and ultimately the man will come for you, anyway. Even physical systems live on borrowed time. In physics "the man" is simply infinity.

Comment: @FlatterMann while you are still standing at the opposite spectrum and paying the "man" just remember Einstein's clever bon-mot: "As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not certain; and as far as they are certain, they do not refer to reality."

Comment: @hyportnex Without wanting to step on Einstein's toes, it's certain that Hamiltonian mechanics on finite phase spaces is not a good approximation of reality. I am afraid that it is also certain that we won't stop pretending to our students that it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering your question, let me just say what I mean by the entropy of an isolated Hamiltonian system. You first choose your favorite set of macrovariables, those that will be used to define the relevant notion of macrostate. You then partition phase space into subsets according to the values taken by these variables (say, up to some given precision). Then, to a given microstate $\omega$, you associate an entropy given by the logarithm of the measure of the subset it belongs to.

For more on this, see, for instance, the paper
[*Macroscopic laws, microscopic dynamics, time's arrow and Boltzmann's entropy*, J. Lebowitz, Physica A 194 (1993) 1-27](https://cmsr.rutgers.edu/images/people/lebowitz_joel/publications/lebowitz_360.pdf), or [this more recent one](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0724) by the same author.

Now, let us turn to your question.

---

You are confusing micro- and macrostates. Suppose that the gas starts at time $0$ with all particles in the left half of the box. This corresponds to a nonequilibrium macrostate (which can be obtained by compressing the gas and inserting a removable wall to keep it there; and removing the wall at time $0$). Let us call $A$ the corresponding subset of phase space.

At positive times, the system evolves, the molecules distributing themselves in the whole box in an essentially homogeneous way, with overwhelming probability. If $A_t$ denotes the image of $A$ at time $t$, then when $t\gg 1$, the vast majority of points in $A_t$ belong to the equilibrium macrostate $B$.

Of course, the Liouville measure of $A_t$ is equal to the Liouville measure of the original set $A$. However, the measure of the set $A_t$ is ridiculously small compared to the measure of the equilibrium macrostate $B$: the points in $A_t$ comprise only a minuscule fraction of the equilibrium macrostate $B$, namely those points corresponding to microstates in which all particles were in the left half of the box at time $0$.

So, if you were to start from any point in $A_t$ and reverse all velocities, the system would return to its initial state at time $0$, displaying a decrease of entropy along the trajectory. However, if you sample a random point in the equilibrium macrostate $B$, then it will almost certainly not belong to $A_t$ and would remain at equilibrium.

So, such Hamiltonian systems are reversible in the mechanical sense: upon reversing velocities, the system follows the same trajectory in reverse. However, it is not reversible in the thermodynamic sense: taking a generic point in the equilibrium macrostate will not lead to the same evolution as selecting a point in the extremely pathological subset $A_t$.

Above, I have assumed that one has waited for the system to reach equilibrium, but the same discussion also applies if you look at what happens at a time $t$ before equilibrium has been reached: the system will find itself in another macrostate, with Liouville measure much larger than that of $A_t$. Sampling a generic point in this macrostate and reversing its velocities will lead to trajectories along which entropy increases (until equilibrium is reached), even though entropy would decrease if you do that for points belonging to $A_t$.

Comment: +1 A nice discussion about these matters is also given in Jaynes' "The second law as physical fact and as human inference", in the section "What does 'reversibility' mean?". In particular, there he emphasizes the connection to experiments.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik, thank you very much for your answer. I need to meditate on it. I should probably think longer before writing but here is what comes to my mind. You say :'However, if you sample a random point in the equilibrium macrostate , then it will almost certainly not belong to $A_t$ and would remain at equilibrium.', but how do we know the part 'and would remain at equilibrium.' ?

Comment: Because the equilibrium macrostate occupies almost all of the phase space, so that a generic trajectory has little choice but to stay there (or go there if it starts out of equilibrium). The papers I linked probably go into quantitative estimates (I read them very long ago, so I don't remember).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Hamiltonian systems don't obey the second law. That the second law wins is because Hamiltonian systems are a poor poor approximation in the infinite time limit. Or, to put it less mildly, the infinite time limit is simply unphysical, even in most trivial cases. Newtonian gravity, for instance, is unstable for all but the most simple examples. Gravitating n-body systems evaporate long before they explore all of their phase space.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't understand. You have a phase space, you can divide it into regions of different macroscopic parameters (hence macro states) and define an entropy function on these macrostates. I don't see any problem. The second law then states that for every experimentally reproducible process, the entropy cannot decrease (roughly speaking).

Comment: @TobiasFünke The phase space of a gravitating n-body problem is infinite. The system can never fill it, hence the assumptions of statistical mechanics don't apply. As soon as such a system kicks out the first body there is one trajectory that goes towards infinity in the radial coordinate and it never stops. The naive ergodic hypothesis for such systems is surely false. Maybe the mathematicians will one day rescue statistical mechanics from itself by finding a properly defined measure that can actually "fill" the phase space under that re-definition, but I am not aware of such a proposal.

Comment: @YvanVelenik, thanks again, I believe that I get it now. Essentially in my reasoning I didn't to take into account the fact that high entropy values correspond to larger volumes in the phase space.